# Update an array php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to update in my database two array that depends on each others. I want to know if it is possible to use `foreach()` to update the data?

```
[reponse] => Array
        (
            [0] => reponse 1
            [1] => reponse 2
            [2] => reponse 3
        )
```

file.php

```
foreach ($reponse as $key=>$value) {

  $values= mysql_real_escape_string($value);    
  $valuesch= mysql_real_escape_string($chimp[$key]);
  $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE  reponses  SET nom_reponse=$values,id_categorie='$categorie',correct='$valuesch' where id_question='$id_question' ")  or die(mysql_error());

}

if ($query2) {

  echo "<br><div class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable'><button aria-hidden='true' data-dismiss='alert' class='close' type='button'>×</button>";
  echo "Reponse Modifer avec succes!! ";
  echo "</div> ";

} else {
  echo " Erreur  reponse!! ";
}
```

I want to know what is the problem in this code? And how to update it correctly?

Comment: Where does $chimp[$key] come from? Also look into myslqi for database use since this code is dangerous to use (too easy to hack)

Comment: thanks for replay , how can i fix that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php (looks a bit daunting, just skip to the examples, it is pretty easy (and less work then concatenating strings).

Comment: sorry but i'm working with mysql , could you please tell how to update an array in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after google and understanding how to use an array i find the solution , to update an array in database i call each value with his key this is the way :

```
[reponse] => Array
        (
            [0] => reponse A
            [1] => reponse B
            [2] => reponse C
        )

    [id_reponse] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 21
        )


foreach ($reponse as $key=>$value) {
        $values= mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $valuescheck= mysql_real_escape_string($chimp[$key]);
        $valuesidr= mysql_real_escape_string($id_reponse[$key]);



        $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE  reponses  SET nom_reponse='$values',correct='$valuescheck' where id_reponse='$valuesidr'  ")  or die(mysql_error());



            }
        if ($query2) {

            echo "<br><div class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable'><button aria-hidden='true' data-dismiss='alert' class='close' type='button'>×</button>";
            echo "Reponse Modifer avec succes!! ";
            echo "</div> ";


        } else {
            echo " Erreur  reponse!! ";
        }
```